# Complex Roots of Polynomials

Tags: complex-numbers

> a) Solve the equation $z^4 = 1$

I got $z = 1, i, - 1, -i $

> (b) Hence solve the equation $(z-1)^4/(z)^4 = 1$

I got $1/2 , 1/(1+i), 1/(1-i)$

> (c) Hence solve the equation $4z^3-6z^2+4z-1=0 $

Question (c) is has the same answer as (b) but I keep getting $1/2, 1/2 + i/2, 1/2 - i/2$.

Little help please? Thanks

Comment: **Hint** What happens when you write your solutions to (b) in the form $a + ib$?

Answer (score 0):

$${1\over 1+i} = {1\over 1+i} \cdot {1-i \over 1-i} = {1-i \over 2} = {1\over2} - {i\over 2}.$$
Similarly, $\displaystyle {1\over 1-i} = {1\over2}+{i\over 2}$.

Comment: $(a+b i)(a-b i)=a^2-b^2i^2=a^2+b^2. $ So for real $a,b,$ not both $0$, we have $(a+b i)(c+d i)=1$ when $c=a/(a^2+b^2$ and $d=-b i/(a^2+b^2).$ So when $a,b $ are real and not both $0$ we have $1/(a+b i)= (a/(a^2+b^2) -b i/(a^2+b^2)=(a-b i)/(a^2+b^2).$